# Node packages that begin with @

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Why do some libraries in node begin with @?  What is the convention?

Probably being completely thick here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope).

> All npm packages have a name. Some package names also have a scope. A scope follows the usual rules for package names (url-safe characters, no leading dots or underscores). When used in package names, preceded by an @-symbol and followed by a slash, e.g.
>
> @somescope/somepackagename

Comment: It would be nice if you explained why someone uses a scoped package and what it's good for.  Could make it a more valuable answer.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful